# How to achieve constant concurrent active users in closed model using Gatling?

Tags: performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

My question is somehow related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564459/how-to-inject-a-constant-number-of-users-in-gatling) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58753311/gatling-rampuser-and-active-user) , but somehow doesn't really answer my question.

My test case is pretty simple, I need to generate constant active concurrent users (e.g. 10 concurrent users) constantly over a period of time (e.g. 60 sec).

My codes look like this

```js
val TestProtocolBuilder: HttpProtocolBuilder = http.baseUrl("https://computer-database.gatling.io")
object Test {

  val test =
    exec(http("Test_Only")
      .get("/computers")
      .check(status.in(200, 404))
    )
}

val TestOnly = scenario("Test Only").exec(Test.test)

setUp(
  TestOnly.inject(
    constantConcurrentUsers(10) during(60 seconds)
  ).protocols(TestProtocolBuilder)
)
```

This [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup/?highlight=open%20workload) says
`constantConcurrentUsers(nbUsers) during(duration)` : Inject so that number of concurrent users in the system is **constant**

I am expecting to get 10 concurrent active users constantly hitting the API for 60 seconds. No more than 10 users and no less than 10 users at any time.

What I see in the HTML report is that the active users at any given time is much higher than 10 (almost double).

[image]

Learning from the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/reports/#active-users-over-time) , it says

> This chart displays the active users during the simulation : total and per scenario.
> “Active users” is neither “concurrent users” or “users arrival rate”. It’s a kind of mixed metric that serves for both open and closed workload models and that represents “users who were active on the system under load at a given second”.

> It’s computed as:
> *(number of alive users at previous second)* + *(number of users that were started during this second)* - *(number of users that were terminated during previous second)*

Questions:

1. Why Gatling keep terminating users and starting new users during the test period? What's the point?
2. How can I get a constant 10 concurrent active users (no more, no less) keep hitting my API for the duration of the test, if `constantConcurrentUsers(10) during(60 seconds)` give me a much higher active users and keep fluctuating during the test period ? I need to stick to my test case and not over-loading the API.
3. In the image above, at that given time `the number of request = 7`  and `the active users = 20`. Does it mean that at that given time, there are 7 active users sending out requests and there are 20 - 7 = 13 active users sitting idle waiting for the responses to come back from the API ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why Gatling keep terminating users and starting new users during the test period? What's the point?

Virtual users' lifespan is driven by your scenario. **Injection** profiles only drive when they are injected/started.
If you want to have your users not terminate after just one requests, add a loop in your scenario.

> How can I get a constant 10 concurrent active users

Nonsensical. As you quoted yourself concurrent != active. I guarantee you have a constant number of concurrent users, meaning exactly 10 users alive at the same time. The thing is that as your scenario only has 1 single request, users terminate right after and are replaced with a new one.

> Does it mean that at that given time, there are 7 active users sending out requests and there are 20 - 7 = 13 active users sitting idle waiting for the responses to come back from the API ?

It means virtual users lifespan overlapped between 2 seconds so they were seen alive in 2 different second buckets.